# React Failed to compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am working on a react app that generates a random profile based on a list of profiles I have setup.

What I am trying to accomplish is randomly generate a number between 1-3 which represents the object in my array. Then pass in the randomly generated number along with an attribute to specify the value to a useState. I am getting an error when trying to do this.

ProfileCard.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

const ProfileCard = () => {
    const [profile, setProfile] = useState("/images/image-bob2.jpg",)
    const [name, setName] = useState("Bob James")
    const [userStats, setUserStats] = useState("80K  803K  1.4K")
    const [city, setCity] = useState("Houston")
    const influencers = [
        {id: 1, pic:"/images/image-bob2.jpg", name:"Bob James", age: "42", city: "Houston", stats: "65K  750K  3.7K" },
        {id: 2, pic:"/images/image-jim2.jpg", name:"Jim Thompson", age: "54", city: "Chicago", stats: "45K  700K  2.3K" },
        {id: 3, pic:"/images/image-victor.jpg", name:"Victor Crest", age: "26", city: "London", stats: "80K  803K  1.4K" }
        
    ]
    const generateUser = () => {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) +1);
        console.log(x)
        const infl = influencers[x]
        const img = infl.pic
        setProfile(pic)
    }
    
    
    return ( 
        <div>
        <main className="main-card">
            <img src="/images/bg-pattern-card.svg" alt="pattern" id="bg-pattern-card"/>
            <img src={profile} alt="Victor" id="victor"/>
            <p className="info-container">
                <detail className="name">
                <strong>{name}</strong> 26<br></br>    
                </detail>
                
                <hr className="section"></hr>
                <p className="followers">{userStats}</p>
            </p>

        </main>
        
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default ProfileCard;
```

[image: Error]

When I console out I can see the value I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `img` not `pic`:

```js
const generateUser = () => {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) +1);
    console.log(x)
    const infl = influencers[x]
    const img = infl.pic
    setProfile(img)          // Change here...
}
```

Fully working, indented, corrected code:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const ProfileCard = () => {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState("/images/image-bob2.jpg");
  const [name, setName] = useState("Bob James");
  const [userStats, setUserStats] = useState("80K  803K  1.4K");
  const [city, setCity] = useState("Houston");
  const influencers = [
    {
      id: 1,
      pic: "/images/image-bob2.jpg",
      name: "Bob James",
      age: "42",
      city: "Houston",
      stats: "65K  750K  3.7K"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      pic: "/images/image-jim2.jpg",
      name: "Jim Thompson",
      age: "54",
      city: "Chicago",
      stats: "45K  700K  2.3K"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      pic: "/images/image-victor.jpg",
      name: "Victor Crest",
      age: "26",
      city: "London",
      stats: "80K  803K  1.4K"
    }
  ];
  const generateUser = () => {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
    console.log(x);
    const infl = influencers[x];
    const img = infl.pic;
    setProfile(img);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <main className="main-card">
        <img
          src="/images/bg-pattern-card.svg"
          alt="pattern"
          id="bg-pattern-card"
        />
        <img src={profile} alt="Victor" id="victor" />
        <p className="info-container">
          <detail className="name">
            <strong>{name}</strong> 26<br></br>
          </detail>
          <hr className="section"></hr>
          <p className="followers">{userStats}</p>
        </p>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfileCard;
```